# Local client data Storage with Angular JS?

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs

I'm working on a quick prototype, and i would like to persist data locally for not having to write Server Side Code.

My application, store data on the $scope, and i have a form on my pages wich add more data on my $scope. But when i'm navigating on the application, i'm loosing my data.

Is it possible to store the data on the session ? and how ?

Is it easier to store data on Google chrome local datastore ?

In advance thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific with you problem area. Not everyone can go through the complete site.

Comment: localStorage and sessionStorage, check them out

Answer (score 4):

You can store data in javascript using either cookies or the local storage feature introduced in HTML5.

- Cookies aren't very intuitive: they have a very tight space limitation, and in order to store any possible javascript type you'll have to do some serializing.
- Local storage is much easier to use, but will only be available to users running a HTML5 compliant web browser.

If you can afford to get your users to use HTML5, then check out this page:
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

If not, you'll have to use cookies:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I haven't been able to find my own works on that field, however I just found this:
https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js
If your users are mostly IE or modern web browser users, this lib seems to be perfect for you.